# How to bind ascii stream to a prepared statement

Tags: java, jdbc, ascii, prepared-statement

I am testing fastload example code from an [official teradata website](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T20208JD.java.txt) . To err on the side of caution ,  I use the sample `FastLoad1.csv` located on their [samples.jar here](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samplePrograms.html)

When I run this sample code, I get an error in this line

```
  pstmtFld.setAsciiStream(1, dataStream, -1); // This method is not implemented
```

**How must setAsciiStream be used with   a prepared statement ?**

Am i using the `setAsciiStream` correctly ?

---

Here is the error message in console

```
 Attempting connection to Teradata with FastLoadCSV.
 Connection to Teradata with FastLoadCSV established.
 Creating a PreparedStatement object with FastLoadCSV.
 Created a PreparedStatement object with FastLoadCSV.
 Checking connection for warnings
 Streaming FastLoad1.csv
SQL State = HY000, Error Code = 1151
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 1151] [SQLState HY000] A failure occurred while setting a parameter value for database table "xxxxxxxxx"."my_table". Details of the failure can be found in the exception chain that is accessible with getNextException.
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:93)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:68)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:1366)
    at T20208JD.main(T20208JD.java:160)

SQL State = HY000, Error Code = 1155
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 1155] [SQLState HY000] The next failure(s) in the exception chain occurred in FastLoadPreparedStatement[0] of 16 FastLoadPreparedStatement(s).
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:93)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:73)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:101)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:1361)
    at T20208JD.main(T20208JD.java:160)

SQL State = HY000, Error Code = 1093
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 1093] [SQLState HY000] This method is not implemented
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:93)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:63)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(FastLoadPreparedStatement.java:759)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:1359)
    at T20208JD.main(T20208JD.java:160)


SQL State = HY000, Error Code = 1151
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 1151] [SQLState HY000] A failure occurred while setting a parameter value for database table "xxxxxxxx"."my_table". Details of the failure can be found in the exception chain that is accessible with getNextException.
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:93)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:68)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:1366)
    at T20208JD.main(T20208JD.java:160)

SQL State = HY000, Error Code = 1155
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 1155] [SQLState HY000] The next failure(s) in the exception chain occurred in FastLoadPreparedStatement[0] of 16 FastLoadPreparedStatement(s).
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:93)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:73)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:101)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:1361)
    at T20208JD.main(T20208JD.java:160)

SQL State = HY000, Error Code = 1093
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 1093] [SQLState HY000] This method is not implemented
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:93)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:63)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(FastLoadPreparedStatement.java:759)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:1359)
    at T20208JD.main(T20208JD.java:160)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Sample failed.
    at T20208JD.main(T20208JD.java:336)
```

Comment: is jdbc smart enough to open, consume, close each stream 3 times in this case?

Comment: What's the table schema?

Comment: The table is exactly as in the sample program http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T20208JD.java.txt I created a FastLoad1.csv file containg three variables exactly as in the sample program

Comment: `is jdbc smart enough to open` . . I do not know that . . . But `pstmtFld.setAsciiStream(1, dataStream, -1); ` throws an error

Comment: Shouldn't you set this as pstmtFld.setAsciiStream(3, dataStream, (int)(new File("FastLoad1.csv")).length());

Comment: I tried this . But in their example they are using `pstmtFld.setAsciiStream(1, dataStream  .   .  `  although they have three fields . This is an official website so i doubt that they have a typo http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T20208JD.java.txt

Comment: In addition `setAsciiStream ` documentation specifies that the first argument stands for the binding question mark

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to compile the example T20208JD, just modified DNS/user/password and it run smoothly on my Mac. So **pstmtFld.setAsciiStream(1, dataStream, -1);** seems to be correct.

I used JDBC 14.10.00.18, you might try to download the latest version 14.10.00.26 from Teradata's Developer Exchange: http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver

I don't think this will fix the problem, but...

Comment: +1 Thank you i updated the jdbc but no result . BTW what connection string are you using ? Mine is `String urlFld   = "jdbc:teradata://XXX/LOGMECH=LDAP,tmode=ANSI,charset=UTF8,LOGDATA='authcid=userid password=mypassword',TYPE=FASTLOAD"; `
`

Comment: Does it differ from your connection string

Comment: I used the one from the example, just modified user and password: "jdbc:teradata://xxx/TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF8,TYPE=FASTLOADCSV". This differs from yours, TYPE=FASTLOAD vs. TYPE=FASTLOADCSV

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is caused by the `-1`, the third parameter, which tells setAsciiStream that the byteStream has `-1` bytes.

When I have used `setAsciiStream()` in the past, I used a `bufferInputStream` and the the size of a `String` if it was over 254 characters.

```
    String convRule;
     ...
    if (convRule.length() > 254) {
        int size = convRule.length();  
        BufferedInputStream bais = new BufferedInputStream( new ByteArrayInputStream( convRule.getBytes() ) );  
        pStmt.setAsciiStream( 4, bais, size );
    }
```

So, comparing mine to yours I can tell the third parameter is different which should be the `length` of the input stream.

Comment: @Buras I'm sorry, `convRule` is just a `String`, I just copied this snippet from some old code where I used `setAsciiStream`.