# How should a sample FastLoad1.csv file look like?

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata

I tried to follow this [example code](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T20208JD.java.txt)

Everything works fine except this line

```
              pstmtFld.setAsciiStream(1, dataStream, -1);
```

It throws SQL exception .

---

I suspect that the sample `FastLoad1.csv` file that i created is not consistent with their example . However i tried to create a very simple file with exactly the same fields . Here is my `FastLoad1.csv`

```
L_INDEX,L_TIMESTAMP,L_TEXT 
1,01/01/13,testText
2,01/01/13,testText
3,01/01/13,testText
4,01/01/13,testText
```

Is it correct csv file . Is it consistent with the sample program ? If yes, why does it throw an exception ?

---

Here is the error message

```
 Attempting connection to Teradata with FastLoadCSV.
 Connection to Teradata with FastLoadCSV established.
 Creating a PreparedStatement object with FastLoadCSV.
 Created a PreparedStatement object with FastLoadCSV.
 Checking connection for warnings
 Streaming FastLoad1.csv
SQL State = HY000, Error Code = 1151
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 1151] [SQLState HY000] A failure occurred while setting a parameter value for database table "xxxxxxxxx"."my_table". Details of the failure can be found in the exception chain that is accessible with getNextException.
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:93)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:68)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:1366)
    at T20208JD.main(T20208JD.java:160)

SQL State = HY000, Error Code = 1155
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 1155] [SQLState HY000] The next failure(s) in the exception chain occurred in FastLoadPreparedStatement[0] of 16 FastLoadPreparedStatement(s).
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:93)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:73)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:101)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:1361)
    at T20208JD.main(T20208JD.java:160)

SQL State = HY000, Error Code = 1093
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 1093] [SQLState HY000] This method is not implemented
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:93)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:63)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(FastLoadPreparedStatement.java:759)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:1359)
    at T20208JD.main(T20208JD.java:160)


SQL State = HY000, Error Code = 1151
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 1151] [SQLState HY000] A failure occurred while setting a parameter value for database table "xxxxxxxx"."my_table". Details of the failure can be found in the exception chain that is accessible with getNextException.
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:93)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:68)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:1366)
    at T20208JD.main(T20208JD.java:160)

SQL State = HY000, Error Code = 1155
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 1155] [SQLState HY000] The next failure(s) in the exception chain occurred in FastLoadPreparedStatement[0] of 16 FastLoadPreparedStatement(s).
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:93)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:73)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:101)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:1361)
    at T20208JD.main(T20208JD.java:160)

SQL State = HY000, Error Code = 1093
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 1093] [SQLState HY000] This method is not implemented
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:93)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:63)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(FastLoadPreparedStatement.java:759)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:1359)
    at T20208JD.main(T20208JD.java:160)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Sample failed.
    at T20208JD.main(T20208JD.java:336)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L_TIMESTAMP is supposed to be a timestamp, but it's a date in the CSV. And it's probably not in the correct format. Do a SHOW TABLE and check the FORMAT, then modify your data accordingly or add it to your INSERT:

```
VALUES(?,? (TIMESTAMP, FORMAT 'mm/dd/yy'),?)
```

And when you use a two-digit year you might not get the expected century (based on some dbscontrol settings)

Comment: Thank you I changed it and even modified to a regular VARCHAR , but still get the same error with `setAsciiStream`

Comment: Which error is returned? Why don't you try it with the FastLoad1.csv found in the samples.jar? The data in the file looks like 1,2010-08-11 13:19:05.1,some text

Comment: Thank you i did not notice that file . I tried using it , but got the same exception

Comment: Thanks , i guess since there is already a sample file there , so there is no issue on the sample file , the issue is with the `setAscii `

Comment: You still didn't show the error message, it might help debugging,

Comment: I have posted the full error message here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239215/how-to-bind-ascii-stream-to-a-prepared-statement Thank You!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is correct csv file.
But, if you want generate dummy data in csv format,
Here is a link http://dummydata.me/ 
Might be useful for you.